# Finding integer $a$, $b$ such that the roots of $3x^2+3(a+b)x+4ab=0$ satisfy $\alpha(\alpha+1)+\beta(\beta+1)=(\alpha+1)(\beta+1)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots, quadratics

> Given that $a$, $b$ are integers with $a>b$ and the two roots $\alpha$, $\beta$ of the equation $$3x^2+3(a+b)x+4ab=0$$
> satisfy the relation
> $$\alpha(\alpha+1)+\beta(\beta+1)=(\alpha+1)(\beta+1)$$ find all the pairs $(a,b)$ of two integers.

I can't seem to approach it properly.

Comment: do you mean to say you cant even start the problem.You could atleast  start by vieta's formula

Comment: Expand the parenthesis on the second equation. Write that in terms of $\alpha\beta$ and $\alpha+\beta$. Also, look up Mathjax, to type and format your equations instead of posting a picture.

Comment: i didnt know about mathjax, will check it out

Comment: i tried to start it using the product and sum of roots but cant work it out completely because of a and b

Comment: well i somehow got a - b = i, idk how am i getting complex solutions tho

Comment: @DhruvGupta: If you show how you got $a-b=i$ (which I think puts you on the right track), I think it would provide sufficient context and would provide something for people to help you with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start from
$$\alpha(\alpha+1)+\beta(\beta+1)=(\alpha+1)(\beta+1)$$
Expand the parenthesis, and move all terms to one side:
$$\alpha^2+\alpha+\beta^2+\beta-\alpha\beta-\alpha-\beta-1=0$$
I am going to write this in terms of the sum of the roots, $\alpha+\beta$, and the product.
$$\begin{align}\alpha^2+\alpha\beta+\beta^2-1&=0\\\alpha^2+2\alpha\beta+\beta^2-\alpha\beta-1&=0\\(\alpha+\beta)^2-\alpha\beta-1=0\end{align}$$
From Vieta's formula, $$\alpha+\beta=-\frac{3(a+b)}3=-(a+b)$$ and $$\alpha\beta=\frac{4ab}3$$
From here $$[-(a+b)]^2-\frac{4ab}3-1=0$$
$$a^2+\frac {2b}3a+(b^2-1)=0$$
$$a_{1,2}=-\frac{b}3\pm\sqrt{\frac{b^2}9-(b^2-1)}=-\frac{b}3\pm\sqrt{1-\frac{8b^2}{9}}$$
For $a$ to be real, $b=0$ or $b=1$. If $b=0$ then $a=\pm1$. Since you are told $a>b$, it means only $a=1$ is good. If $b=1$, $a=-\frac 13\pm\frac13$. One solution is not integer, the other is less than $b$.

**Note:** As mentioned in the comments, there is a sign mistake in the sign after the second equation. The third equation should be $$\alpha^2+\beta^2-\alpha\beta-1=0$$
After that $$(\alpha+\beta)^2-3\alpha\beta-1=0$$
With the Vieta,
$$[-(a+b)]^2-3\frac{4ab}3-1=0\\(a-b)^2=1$$
Since $a>b$, then $$a=b+1$$

Comment: Check again: I believe that $(\alpha+\beta)^2=3\alpha\beta+1$ is what follows from $\alpha(\alpha+1)+\beta(\beta+1)=(\alpha+1)(\beta+1)$. Between your second and third equations above, the sign of $\alpha\beta$ changes.

Comment: Thanks @robjohn for catching that. I will modify my answer

Answer (score 2):

Because $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are roots of $3x^2+3(a+b)x+4ab$, [Vieta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas) says
$$
\alpha+\beta=-a-b\quad\text{and}\quad\alpha\beta=\frac43ab\tag1
$$
Since $\alpha(\alpha+1)+\beta(\beta+1)=(\alpha+1)(\beta+1)$, we have
$$
(\alpha+\beta)^2=3\alpha\beta+1\tag2
$$
Plugging $(1)$ into $(2)$, we have
$$
(a+b)^2=4ab+1\iff(a-b)^2=1\tag3
$$
Since $a\gt b$, we get
$$
a=b+1\tag4
$$